# Why is the Google Places API is randomly returning "Not Authorized" errors?

Tags: google-places-api

I'm getting very strange results with the google places API.

I have the following very simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <input id="pac-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
    <script>
        var initMap = function () {
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('pac-input'));
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MyKey]&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and what I'm finding is that it will work for about the first 10 keystrokes, then the service returns a "This API project is not authorized to use this API." error message.

However, when I run this same code on Plunker, it works perfectly all the time.

Here are a couple of screenshots from my localhost:

[image]

[image]

I have Google Maps Geocoding API and Google Maps JavaScript API enabled.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Yes this is very weird. I've had the same issue. Still trying to figure something out. I hate working on non-reproducable bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me enabling the "Google Places API Web Service" in addition to the "Google Maps JavaScript API" made it work.